# Как посчитать количество строк по часам?

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблица (oracle) запросов с датой/временем типа

```
| id| req_time                     |
|---|------------------------------|
| 1 | 02.07.16 10:04:43,984000000  |
| 2 | 02.07.16 10:04:42,397000000  |
| 3 | 02.07.16 10:04:39,718000000  |
```

Как посчитать количество строк (запросов) по часам в течении периода (например, недели)?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select trunc(req_time,'HH'), count(1)
  from table
 where req_time between TO_DATE('01072016','DDMMYYYY')
                    and TO_DATE('07072016','DDMMYYYY')+0.9999942
 group by trunc(req_time,'HH')
```

Собственно условие в where выбирает нужный вам период, а trunc усекает дату до часов. Константа `0.9999942` для приближения времени в дне к 23:59:59.9.

Comment: Спасибо. Похоже на правду, но остался один вопрос: я добавил сортировку:
<pre>
select trunc(created,'HH'), count(1)
 from connector_data
 where created between TO_DATE('01072016','DDMMYYYY')
                    and TO_DATE('07072016','DDMMYYYY')+0.9999942
 group by trunc(created,'HH')
order by trunc(created,'HH'); </pre>
И получилось примерно так:
<pre>
| trunc(created,'HH')| count(1) |
|-------------------------|------------|
|01.07.16                 |   37        |
|01.07.16                 |    46       |
</pre>
Как сделать, чтобы еще было видно время (какой конкретно час)?

Comment: @DmitryRoo Время должно быть видно. по крайней мере там же возвращается поле типа datetime. Может у вас клиентская часть по умолчанию из него просто дату берет. Можете попробовать на стороне оракла его преобразовать к строке `select TO_CHAR(trunc(created,'HH'),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24'), ...`